# Error when accessing cursor elements

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to get all the `IDs` in the table by cursor. The table has 4 rows, and when I try to access the cursor by any index aside from 0 , the App crashes.

Guys, the problem still exists and even c.getInt(0) doesn't work...I really dont know where my mistake is???

the logcat also suggests that the error might be comes from

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "id="+dbd.getIDs()[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I mean `c.getint(0)` returns the id, `c.getint(2)` returns error. Here is the code:

```
public int []getIDs() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteCursor c = (SQLiteCursor) db.rawQuery("SELECT " + BaseColumns._ID + " FROM Demo ", null);

    int []r = new int[c.getCount()];
    c.moveToFirst();

    do{
        r[c.getPosition()] = c.getInt(0); 
    }while(c.moveToNext());

    c.close();
    db.close();
    return r;       
}
```

Comment: ndroid.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0 02-27 15:27:02.957: E/AndroidRuntime(1388): at

Pull your database off of the emulator with DDMS.  Check it with the Firefox SQL Manager to verify its contents and to test your SQL statements.

Comment: your cursor is empty. check your tabe data.

Comment: ohh, yes it was empty i disabled the function the populate the table..

Comment: now it works..but I still have a question..I would posted above

Comment: try to change this  do{
        r[c.getPosition()] = c.getInt(0); 
    }while(c.moveToNext()); to   int i=0; do{
        r[i++] = c.getInt(0); 
    }while(c.moveToNext());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`c.getInt(0)` return only value of first colunn from current row.

try this code:

```
do{
int r = c.getInt(0);
Log.d("Your class name","id value = "+r);
}while(c.moveToNext());
```

Comment: I posted my attemps above but I still gave the same error, even c.getInt(0) gives eror also!!!!!1

Comment: try to change c.getInt(0); to c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));

Comment: and make shure that your table is not empty, and typr of BaseColumns._ID is INTRGER

Comment: also move c.moveToFirst(); before do{...}while

Answer (score 1):

Your select is a projection onto the ID column (select columns from ..., columns are the column ids you are interested in, and you specified just one). Thus the answer just has one column, namely the ID. Any access to columns with index > 0 will not work.

To access the other columns name them in the projection in your query.

Comment: the problem is, when I try to access c.getInt(1) or c.getInt(2) the App.Crashs...only c.get(0) works

Comment: Yes, select A from table ... will always deliver rows with just one column (independent of the amount of columns in the table, provided there is a columns A), and a c.getInt(1) will crash. With select A,B from table ... will deliver two columns per row, and c.getInt(1) will work (if B is integer valued), but c.getInt(2) will crash. If you need all the columns you need to name them all or use select * from table ...

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine Cursor as a table. There are rows and columns. And a cursor is pointing on a particular row in this table. Thus, to get all id's you should move across all rows.

`c.getInt(ind)` In this statement index is pointing on the column with index ind. Thus, in your code you try to get the second and third column and according to your code there is no these column.

To get a proper code you should create a loop and traverse all rows of your cursor. Also you should use `c.getInt(0)` to get the columns values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are selecting the appropriate Data, your problem is that you're not preparing the Cursor to be iterated.

Before iterating, call:

```
c.moveToFirst();
```

Like this:

```
int []r = new int [c.getCount()];
c.moveToFirst();
    do{
        r[c.getPosition()] = c.getInt(0);
    }while(c.moveToNext());

    c.close();
    db.close();
    return r;
```

This is well indicated in LogCat.  I can't remember how it's put, but the message is very suggestive.  Please post as much of the Log as possible, especially the good bits.

Also, I modified 'r' to be an array.  As it was you were only returning the value of the last row.

Comment: ndroid.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0 02-27 15:27:02.957: E/AndroidRuntime(1388)

Comment: could you please tell me what does it mean?? how the cursor could be outbound while moveToNext is tested?